# Sorting columns with aliases

Tags: wp-list-table

I am new to WP_LIST_TABLE and working on someone's else code. I have a couple of joins my query which you

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_o_students st
INNER JOIN wp_o_schools sc
ON st.school_id = sc.school_id
INNER JOIN wp_marks_list ml
ON st.student_id = ml.student_id
ORDER BY $orderby
LIMIT %d OFFSET %d
```

How do I set these columns to be sortable ?

```
'school_id' => __('School ID', 'olympiad'),
'student_id' => __('Student ID', 'olympiad'),
'test_code' => __('Test Code', 'olympiad'),
'division' => __('Division', 'olympiad'),
'class_highest' => __('Class Highest', 'olympiad'),
'cutoff_marks' => __('Cutoff Marks', 'olympiad'),
'scored_marks' => __('Scored Marks', 'olympiad'),
'marks' => __('Marks', 'olympiad'));
```

If I put aliases before column names, it won't work. It shows no results in table and its empty. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found out that this can be achieved in 1 way. If I specify specific columns that I need instead of using * in my query, it will work.

Example:

```
SELECT st.student_id
FROM wp_o_students st
INNER JOIN wp_o_schools sc
ON st.school_id = sc.school_id
INNER JOIN wp_marks_list ml
ON st.student_id = ml.student_id
ORDER BY $orderby
LIMIT %d OFFSET %d
```

And for table columns:

```
'student_id' => __('Student ID', 'olympiad'),
```

Since there will be only 1 column with student_id, it will be used.